# Getting more detail about transactions/ invoices/ donatons

Tags: civireport

I'd like to get more detail on what exactly each transaction contains. The report I have lists the donor, transaction number, date, amount and note. It's possible to get the shipping cost by drilling into individual transactions - how can I create a column in the primary report for that? The note field lists what items we shipped (eg tshirt, or stickers) how can I get a quantity (Eg, how many shirts)? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Julie-Ann you may need to add some screenshots or more info so folk don't have to guess what is meant by 'quantity'. Are you using Price Sets. If so this extension may be helpful to you https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport